# sql server to linq group by having

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

i'm learning linq.

I have in sql server:

```
create table Something(id int, num int)

insert into Something(id, num) values(1, 10);
insert into Something(id, num) values(1, 10);
insert into Something(id, num) values(2, 7);
insert into Something(id, num) values(2, 7);
insert into Something(id, num) values(2, 7);
insert into Something(id, num) values(3, 5);
insert into Something(id, num) values(3, 5);
insert into Something(id, num) values(3, 5);
insert into Something(id, num) values(3, 5);
insert into Something(id, num) values(3, 5);
insert into Something(id, num) values(3, 5);
insert into Something(id, num) values(4, 5);

select id 
from something
group by id, num
having count(*) < num
```

the result is : 4, 2 and 1

I am trying in linq:

```
var query =
(from m in lst
group m by new { m.id, m.num } into g
where g.Count() < m.num).ToList();
```

I want to compare g.Count() with "num" field, but something is wrong in my code

Thansk for your help!

Comment: What is happening. Can you be more specific than "not running"? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `g.key.num` instead of `m.num`:

```
var query =
(from m in lst
group m by new { m.id, m.num } into g
where g.Count() < g.key.num).ToList();
```